# How to remove first pin image after calling refresh button in iOS?

Tags: ios7, ios6

I have map view and I am showing car on my map view using map view annotation. But after
click on refresh button. first image is remain and update pin image showing with.
         I want to remove first pin image after refresh button pressed.

Thank You.

Comment: Are you using [self.view addSubview:MapView]; when the refresh button is called?

Comment: No.. I am not calling addSubView method

Comment: Can you post some sample code of how the view is being updated?

Comment: I am just updating latitude and longitude value from web service to my mkpin Annotation.

Comment: Ok, but can you post the method that is called when the refresh button is tapped? Without this method, it will be hard to help fix the problem.